# How can i authenticate my webapp on Google Clooud Storage via REST API?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage, oauth2-playground

I'm building a webapp on bubble.io and i wanted to use the Cloud Storage API, to storage files and images. But with bubble, i can only send HTTP Requests, so i'm having a hard time trying to authenticate my app using REST API (i'll use a Service Account on this app). How can i authenticate to use the Cloud Storage API using REST API?

Comment: Service accounts are meant for backend to backend communication. So one approach you could evaluate is to use the service account plugin https://bubble.io/plugin/google-service-account-1605833704975x195806677045870600

Comment: Hey, thanks, it helped a lot. I ask another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75804768/how-can-i-upload-images-to-google-cloud-storage-using-bubble-io/75806100?noredirect=1#comment133721137_75806100

Could you please help me on this one too?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

As mentioned by @Kris:

"Service accounts are meant for backend to backend communication. So one approach you could evaluate is to use the service account plugin [bubble.io/plugin/…](https://bubble.io/plugin/google-service-account-1605833704975x195806677045870600)"

Comment: Hey, i'm new to stackoverflow, what is community wiki?