# How can i upload images to Google Cloud Storage using Bubble.io?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bubble.io

I'm using the API Connector to use the Cloud Storage API, to store my data, but i'm having a hard time trying to upload images.

In the example bellow i'm trying to upload a png image:

This is how my API call is set-up

[image: This is how my API call is set-up:]

I can sucessfully create the object, but the contentType is always created like this

[image: I can sucessfully create the object, but the contentType is always created like this:]

Even if i go to Google Cloud Console and change the type of the object to image/png, the image doesn't open. I think i'm passing the data-binary param in a wrong way, but i don't know how i should pass it.

Here's the documentation that i'm following:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects

Thanks :)

Comment: Your body type is form-data, which is probably wrong.  data-binary is a `curl` argument and not to be used outside curl context. Your body type could be something like `Raw` or `multipart` ?

Comment: @Kris yes, it could be Raw, how could i write it correctly?